# Python number the occurrences of elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Having a problem when working on lists

trying to figure out how to number elements if they appear more than once, from the second appearance i want to add the number near the '@':

for example:

```
['example@company.com', 'example@company.com', 'none@comapny.com','example@company.com']
```

wanted output :

```
['example@company.com', 'example2@company.com', 'none@comapny.com','example3@company.com']
```

Code so far :

```
count_apper=Counter(mails_list)
    for values in count_apper.items():
        for mail in mails_list:
            if values[0]==mail:
                number+=1
                temp_var=mail.split("@") 
                temp_var[0]=temp_var[0]+f"{number}"
                temp_var="@".join(temp_var)
                print(temp_var)
            number=1
```

Output :

```
example1@company.com
example2@company.com
example2@company.com
none2@company.com
```

Comment: You should try to write down some code, and then ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would base my answer off of a `collections.Counter()` I think. It will do some of the work for you.

```
import collections

addresses = ['example@company.com', 'example@company.com', 'none@comapny.com', 'example@company.com']

results = []

for address, count in collections.Counter(addresses).items():
    # add a "first" address as is
    results.append(address)

    # If there were other occurrences add them
    for i in range(1, count):
        results.append(f"{i+1}@".join(address.split("@")))

print(results)
```

This should give you:

```
['example@company.com', 'example2@company.com', 'example3@company.com', 'none@comapny.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the list and use a `dict` to keep track of the number of occurences of a specific address. To add text before the `@` sign, you can use the `.split` method of `str`. A possible implementation looks as follows.

```
addresses = ['example@company.com', 'example@company.com', 'none@comapny.com', 'example@company.com']
occurence_count = {}
transformed = []
for a in addresses:
    count = occurence_count.get(a, 0) + 1
    occurence_count[a] = count

    name, domain = a.split('@')
    if count > 1:
        transformed.append(f'{name}{count}@{domain}')
    else:
        transformed.append(a)

print(transformed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
j=['example@company.com', 'example@company.com', 'none@comapny.com','example@company.com']
count=1
k=j.copy()
for i in range(len(j)):
    
    if k.count(k[i])>1:
        m=[char for char in j[i]]
        m.insert(j[i].index('@'),str(count)
        )
        count+=1
        j[i]=''.join(m)
print (j)
```